# Inner join of two data frames still showing all values

Tags: r, join, dataframe

I have two data frames, one for store and one for sales:

```
store <- data.frame(StoreID=c(1,2,3,4), StoreName=c("McDonalds", "A&W", "Burger King", "Wendy's"))
sales <- data.frame(StoreID=c(1,2,1,1,2,2), ItemID=c(2,2,3,4,4,5), SalesQty=c(10,20,30,40,50,60))  

store    
#StoreID   StoreName
#      1   McDonalds
#      2         A&W
#      3 Burger King
#      4     Wendy's 

sales  
#StoreID ItemID SalesQty  
#      1      2       10  
#      2      2       20  
#      1      3       30  
#      1      4       40  
#      2      4       50  
#      2      5       60
```

I want to merge them, so that I can see StoreName for each sales transaction:

```
merged <- merge(sales, store, by = "StoreID")

merged
#StoreID ItemID SalesQty StoreName  
#      1      2       10 McDonalds  
#      1      3       30 McDonalds
#      1      4       40 McDonalds
#      2      2       20       A&W
#      2      4       50       A&W
#      2      5       60       A&W
```

Now I want to know for each StoreName in the merged data frame, how many different items were sold:

```
tapply(merged$ItemID, merged$StoreName, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))

#A&W Burger King   McDonalds     Wendy's 
#  3          NA           3          NA
```

My question is, why does the tapply result show "Burger King" and "Wendy's" even though they aren't in the merged data frame?

Comment: they are `factors`, so the levels still exist

Comment: if you make the values characters by going `data.frame(StoreID = ..., ..., stringsAsFactors = F)` when creating the data frames, you won't see them in the output.

Comment: `droplevels` is the way to get rid of unused factor levels, e.g. `with(droplevels(merged), tapply(ItemID, StoreName, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `store$StoreName` is a `factor`. When creating the store data frame, setting the argument `stringsAsFactor` to `FALSE` will ensure those store names with no matching element in `sales` are dropped during the `merge`.

```
sales <- data.frame(StoreID=c(1,2,1,1,2,2), ItemID=c(2,2,3,4,4,5), SalesQty=c(10,20,30,40,50,60))  
store <- data.frame(StoreID=c(1,2,3,4), StoreName=c("McDonalds", "A&W", "Burger King", "Wendy's"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
merged <- merge(sales, store, by = "StoreID")
tapply(merged$ItemID, merged$StoreName, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))

  #A&W McDonalds 
  #  3         3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```
merged$StoreName <- factor(merged$StoreName)
tapply(merged$ItemID, merged$StoreName, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))

#  A&W McDonalds 
#    3         3
```